# VLC player error. When i install it it shows this error

Tags: apt, dependencies, vlc

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2) but 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.2 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 is to be installed
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 is to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Comment: How are you installing?

Comment: Yes i'm installing it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I recommend you to try installing the dependencies by entering the cmd ,

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If this doesn't works out , try installing chromium browser, which will install better libc dep which will be less hectic if you are not much familiar in handling deps.

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Now install VLC , now your problem might be sorted out by now.

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Thats it.